# Issue: Bootstrap 4 modal shifting my page contents to the left

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using in my application the modal example from Bootstrap site found here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

It works fine except for a small glitch: anytime I launch the modal my whole page content (behind the modal) shifts to the left and when I close the modal the contents shifts back to the original place. Not a big deal but it's kind of annoying.

I put the code here: https://www.codeply.com/p/TzBEwRHeNp

*PS: I realized that not always the problem will occur. I am using Chrome browser (Windows 7) and I usually keep the debugger opened (F12) that's when it happens in a certain screen width. I don't know if it is caused by the debugger feature or if the issue is triggered by a specific screen width (that may be a problem if my user has a viewport that matches this width).*

Anyone has experienced it or/and knows a possible fix to this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your code? Maybe put it in a code sandbox would be better to help you.

Comment: I put the code here: https://www.codeply.com/p/TzBEwRHeNp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the scrollbar width. The Bootstrap models require to have a `modal-open` class set on the `body` to counter for this. When modals are shown, the scrollbar gets eliminated from the body (`overflow: hidden;`) and added to the `modal-dialog`. This makes the `modal-backdrop` unscrollable and modals with large content scrollable.

```
// .modal-open      - body class for killing the scroll
// .modal           - container to scroll within
// .modal-dialog    - positioning shell for the actual modal
// .modal-content   - actual modal w/ bg and corners and stuff
```

From the documentation you actually need those four classes to make it workly smoothly.
Is it possible you missed one of those? The issue is not visible in your codeply.

Perhaps you get any wiser by reading the [scss code from github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_modal.scss).